# Filling a box with tools

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

As in this image,

[image]

I want to fill a box with some tools. I applied rigid body (active) to the tools and box (passive). All objects are made in real-world scale. The object's shape is changed to MESH type. I decreased the margin to 5 mm and ran the simulation. And the result is:

[image]

Tools go away from the box. If you want to look at the settings I applied to the simulation, the Blender file is here:

[test.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RVm4Aa7KiNt4v0GZQ0-1E-QT3_8nEFp-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turn down collision margin to 0 here:

[image]

After that they will fall down.

You should also reduce friction to get a realistic result.